# Retrieve a single property from document

Tags: python, mongodb

Good day everyone.
Suppose we have a collection and a document which looks something like this:

```
    test_doc = {
    "ID" : "123",
    "a" : [
                    {
                        'x' : "/",
                        'y' : "2000",
                        'z' : "1000"
                    },
                    {
                        'x' : "/var",
                        'y' : "3500",
                        'z' : "3000"
                    }
           ]

      }
```

What i need is to retrieve a single property a.z .
In MongoDB i'm using the following query:

```
db.testcol.find({"ID":"123","a.x":"/"},{'a.z':1})
```

which returns this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("skipped"), "a" : [ { "z" : "1000" }, { "z" : "3000" } ] }
```

As you can see it returns all the z properties, but i need only the first one or the second when condition is `{"ID":"123","a.x":"/var"}`
So, the question is: how do i get a single property in this situation? Is it just a matter of bad design or should i somehow process the returned document in code (python)? Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB 2.0 and older, this is not possible.  What you want to do is return a specific element of the array - but that is not what your projection is actually doing, it will just return the whole array and then the z element of each one.

However, with 2.2 (rc2 as of writing this answer), things have gotten a bit better.  You can now use [$elemMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch) as part of your projection (see [SERVER-2238](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2238) for details) so that you only pull back the required array element.  So, try something like this:

```
db.foo.find({"ID":"123",'a':{$elemMatch:{'x':"/"}}},{_id : 0, 'a.$': 1})
//returns
{ "a" : [ { "x" : "/", "y" : "2000", "z" : "1000" } ] }
```

Or, just use $elemMatch in the projection itself, which you may think is cleaner:

```
db.foo.find({"ID":"123"},{_id : 0, 'a':{$elemMatch:{'x':"/"}}})
//returns 
{ "a" : [ { "x" : "/", "y" : "2000", "z" : "1000" } ] }
```

So, now, at least the array returned is only the one containing only the entries you want and you can simply reference the relevant z element (elemMatch projections on a subdocument are not yet supported).

Last but not least, in 2.2 we have the aggregation framework, and one of the things it can do (with the `$project` operator, is to reshape your documents and change sub documents and array elements into top level arrays.  To get your desired result, you would do something like this:

```
db.foo.aggregate( 
        {$match : {"ID":"123"}},  
        {$unwind : "$a"},  
        {$match : {"a.x":"/"}},  
        {$project : {_id : 0, z : "$a.z"}}
)
```

The result looks like this:

```
{ "result" : [ { "z" : "1000" } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Adam. Actually i was thinking towards $elemMatch too, but i was kinda confused about how it works. Your answer made things clear for me now.

Comment: I also added an example of how to do this with the aggregation framework - I needed to test it first before I could include it :)

Comment: Wow aggregation seems to be a pretty neat feature. Thx for the example, rly useful :)